# When returning an iterator in Python 3, should `yield from` be preferred over `return`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

In Python 3, we have the `yield from` keyword, which is useful for splicing the contents of an existing iterator between other `yield` statements. However, if we only want to yield all the results from an existing iterator, we can achieve the same result using either `yield from iterable` or simply `return iterable`. Obviously if you need your code to work in Python 2 as well as Python 3, you are locked in to the `return` option. But if you are only targetting Python 3, is there a strong reason to prefer one over the other? The `yield from` version has the advantage of making it immediately obvious to anyone reading the code that this function is returning an iterator. On the other hand, I imagine that the naive implementation of `yield from` might be slower than simply returning an existing iterator, but CPython or other implementations might have optimized this case. So which of the following should be preferred?

```
def returns_an_iterator():
    return iter([1,2,3])

def yields_from_an_iterator():
    yield from iter([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning the iterator will be more efficient, removing extra indirection on each `next` call. However, note that the semantics are different.

If you `return` the iterator, your function is an ordinary function. The body will execute immediately when called, and things like context manager `__exit__`s and `finally` blocks in your function will execute before the iterator is returned and before any values are produced from the iterator.

If you `yield from` the iterator, your function is a generator function. The body will not execute when the function is called, and if the `yield from` happens inside a `with` or `try` block, `__exit__` functions and `finally` blocks won't run until the generator is exhausted. Additionally, since the returned generator is not the iterator you `yield from` over, any additional functionality of the underlying iterator object will be unavailable.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation going beyond just the performance difference. I suspected there might be subtle differences in behavior between the two despite the apparent equivalence.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have other reasons to wrap an iterator, you should return it directly.

```
def with_return():
    return range(10)
>>> with_return()
range(0, 10)
```

If you use `yield from`, you'll create an intermediate generator and add overhead when each value is read from the iterator. Returning the iterator directly will avoid that overhead.

```
def with_yield_from():
    yield from range(10)
>>> with_yield_from()
<generator object with_yield_from at 0x030DEDB0>
```